# How to auto run openbox on debian minimum installation

Tags: debian, autostart, autologin, openbox

Debian 10
I install only printer deamon and utilites, then install:

```
apt-get install aptitute
aptitude install xorg openbox
```

And i do manually login and starting

```
startx
```

How to start openbox on power on? (xdm no need, it not must required enter login/password)

Answer (score 0):

You need [display manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager) like:

- slim
- lightdm
- xdm

Use LightDM and see manual to configure automatic login https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM